# Alternative to Silverlight and Blend for an application with RIA-like-Features

Tags: silverlight, qt, ria, blend

I'm evaluating Silverlight for a RIA right now. A large amount of the Gui is to be designed by people without programming skills. Visually the application should be very appealing, animations, smooth transitions and so on are a big plus for us. Blend and Silverlight seem to be tailored very well to fit this requirement. However it does need the runtime which is somewhat acceptable for us but also a little disadvantage.

So, do you know an mature Ria-like alternatives (similar ease of development, all-in-one-happy-package without runtime) outside of this ecosystem? I had a look at Qt and the designer but I'm not sure what to make of it in the moment with all the buzz about it and if it is fitting to our needs.

Are there other alternatives you can recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this statement: "it does need the runtime which is somewhat acceptable for us but also a little disadvantage. "? What RIA delivery system would you imagine exists without the need of a runtime? Even a HTML5 based system needs the very latest in browsers.

Comment: Well, I was hoping that there are already RIA-like solutions based on JavaScript or pure Asp.Net or something similar. I'm just starting to get into the topic though. Maybe the question should be: Is there a solution that gives me comparable ease of development and Blends advantages without relying on a runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure how it should work. Of course you can create your application in HTML5, but still it needs browser as "runtime". Asp.net is server side technology, so it can't be done as a client technology.

Comment: I need the browser, of course. And Asp.Net is server-side. But I'm searching for a all-in-one package. So I also need a server tech that plays well with my client tech. I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with .NET technologies and looking at Silverlight from that perspective, its may be the way to go in that you will be using the same tools. Silverlight is also cross-platform on desktops.

Adobe Air as far as I can tell can be many things, one or more combininations of flash, flex, javascript, html. This is also cross platform in terms of desktop machines.

Html/jQuery/Javascript is another option, this also enables usage on mobile devices.

There are 3rd party plugins/add-ons and components for most of these technologies that help with both features and the visual aspect of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/), but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand, here is what I hear you saying: you want designers to design the UI and developers to develop the code.

Your problem is that developing for Silverlight requires the Silverlight runtime? I'm not sure I get this, but here are some thoughts:

1) If your designers are running Windows you can install just Expression Studio and Blend should include all you need for them to do their work in Blend.

2) If your designers are NOT running Windows, they can't use Blend.  They can still do their design work in Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop because those assets can then be imported into Blend.  Of course, whoever does the import will need a Windows machine with at least Blend installed: in that sort of scenario we call that person an "integrator", and there are folks out there who specialize in that sort of work.

3) If your developers are going to create Silverlight applications, they will need Windows and .NET developers tools (preferably Visual Studio).  To paraphrase what AnthonyWJones said earlier: how can you develop for a platform without having the platform?

In my mind, having Visual Studio and Blend is the "all-in-one happy package", but that's just me. :)

Comment: No, my problem is that the customers need the runtime. That's why I had to make sure there are no alternatives who don't use a runtime out there. I second the opinion that VS+Blend is the best package available as far as I know. But who knows, maybe someone built a great designer that creates css+asp.net+javascript+html-code without writing a single line of code and I don't know about it. ;)

Comment: OK, that makes more sense :-)  I'm pretty sure Air has a runtime as well, so it seems to me your stuck with an HTML/CSS/JavaScript type solution.